# Codedui fail to click on Hidden control and Bounding Rectangle issues

Tags: c#, automation, coded-ui-tests

I have Web based application , where I am trying Click on a Hyperlink , In my automation development machine , it works fine , but If I run the same on some other machine (VM's), say testing machine using Test agent and Test Controller through MTM . I am getting the following error message

Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToPerformActionOnHiddenControlException: Cannot perform 'Click' on the hidden control. Additional Details: 
TechnologyName:  'Web'.

I followed few msdn blogs and uninstalled the security update on my windows and currently I am using the IE11 on my dev box and testing box and VS 2010 premium on my dev box

http://i1.blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/09/17/coded-ui-mtm-issues-on-internet-explorer-with-kb2870699.aspx?PageIndex=4
but this did not work for me .

I also tried using the BoundingRectangle property this way below

```
UITestControlCollection uic = link.FindMatchingControls();

   foreach (UITestControl ui in uic)
{
     if (ui.BoundingRectangle.Width > 0)
      {
             Mouse.Click(ui);
             break;
      }

}
```

but I get this error:

Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotAvailableException: The following element is no longer available: IE web control; Process Id [5136], window handle [1705946] Additional Details:

I request for help on this . As I am struggling to find the real reason  why this is happening. The Hyperlink is visible on screen but , i do not understand why it is hidden for Playback , Also i cannot debug this as it is on VM and I am using Teat Agent to run this from MTM.

Request for the Help

Thanks,

Keerthi

Comment: I don't like using Find Controls because it is very slow.  When I need to enumerate through controls I make my own list List<TextBox> boxes = new List<TextBox>() {textbox1,textbox2, textbox3, textbox4};  It is hard coded but it runs much faster than find controls.

Comment: I did add Find Matching Controls , assuming that I have another hidden control with the same name , but I am having only single control on the web page

Comment: Make sure you are going to same url on working and non working machines.  The url may not be reachable on other machines.  It could be a  proxy issue but it is too early to tell.

Comment: I am using different URL on different machines, the URL cannot be accessed outside the VM

Comment: Then make sure url is valid on machines where it is failing.

Comment: Yes it is valid, i am able to perform other actions on that site , with same search properties

Comment: Are you testing for visible = true?  You can't click on an invisible control.  Find Controls is returning both visible and invisible controls.

Comment: I am not checking any visible= true , i might try using it

Comment: The error message says : .FailedToPerformActionOnHiddenControlException

Comment: i tried checking for VisibleOnly to True, but then , playback is failing to find control with the given search properties , is this the error i am getting

Comment: yes ierror message says : .FailedToPerformActionOnHiddenControlException

Comment: What happens if you do search and then filter results on Visible?

Comment: If i apply IsVisibleOnly to True i get playback failed to find control with given search properties

Comment: Have you tried to publish application and install on other machines?  For an application to run on another machine the version of Net Library has to be exactly the same.  The publish will bring two machine to equivalent levvel.

Comment: hi jdweng, I do nothave access to install any application on the machines , but the same web application is deployed on the two machines that i am working with , i have checked that with developer

Comment: Doesn't that imply it is the machine and not your code?

Comment: Even I suspect the same , i have tried running automation on the same URL from my automation box and this works absolutely fine .

Comment: Publishing the application will update windows dlls so the installed machine has same version  dlls as in build machine.

Comment: yes the installed version of dll 's are same in the both the machines

Comment: What do you mean by installed version of dlls.  I was talking about windows dlls that are used by the Net Library.  Do you have same version of Net installed on all machines including updates?

Comment: yes the windows dll's used by .NET Library are of same version , but the updates installed are different

Comment: So a bug(missing update)  in the dlls is probably the root cause of issue.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem is that your control is hidden, try using the bounding rectangle to create and click on a "clickpoint" to click on as a workaround for the hidden control.

```
var clickPoint = new Point(control.BoundingRectangle.X +     control.BoundingRectangle.Width / 2, control.BoundingRectangle.Y +     control.BoundingRectangle.Height / 2);

Mouse.Click(clickPoint);
```